# Performance tuning powershell script failing with System.outOfMemoryException

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quest

I have the following PowerShell script that is failing after 30min of execution with an System.outOfMemoryException

```
$csv = get-content "C:\test\groups.txt" 
$result = $csv | foreach-object { 
$group=$_ 
get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 | 
select-object    sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type
} 
$result | export-csv C:\test\groupMembers.csv -Delimiter "|" -notypeinformation
```

What the script does, is getting the content from the text file `groups.txt` which is a list of all groups found in the Active Directory, then for each group, it extracts in csv the group name, member name and member type.

If I am not wrong, the script is processing too much data into memory and fails when the limit is reached, is there a way to tune the script for example to release the memory every time a group is proceeded or something?

Comment: How about not bothering saving the `$result` and just pipe into `export-csv`. How big is the `groups.txt`? You could also use `-ReadCount` of `get-content`. That would require you to use the pipe again.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for the quick answer, I am a complete noob in PowerShell, could you please illustrate your answer how to get rid of $result and use -ReadCount? the content of .txt file is about 24000 line and the expected result to export to csv is about 1m row

Answer (score 1):

My organization is not large enough for me to run into these sort of issue but some of the initial suggestions you should consider are removing the `$result` variable as that will save *all* progress in memory before writing to file.

```
$csv = get-content "C:\test\groups.txt" 

$csv | foreach-object { 
    $group=$_ 
    get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 | 
    select-object    sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type
} | export-csv C:\test\groupMembers.csv -Delimiter "|" -notypeinformation
```

To continue, assuming you have at least PowerShell 3.0, you could use the `-ReadCount` which will pull multiple lines at once instead of one line at a time. Not 100% sure if it will help your situation though

```
get-content "C:\test\groups.txt" -ReadCount 500 | foreach-object { 
    $group=$_ 
    get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 | 
    select-object    sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type
} | export-csv C:\test\groupMembers.csv -Delimiter "|" -notypeinformation
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try reading that file using a stream instead of get-content to keep memory usage to a minimum.

Something like this:

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "c:\test\groups.txt"
$outstream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\test\groupMembers.csv"
while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
  # $line has your line, parse to get each piece of csv

  #create a csv string and stream it to the output file
  $s = "`"{0}`",`"{1}`",`"{2}`",`"{3}`"" -f ($each,$piece,$of,$csv)
  $outstream.WriteLine($s)
}
$file.close()
$outstream.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the output to export-CSV ? it should be done before or after $file.close() ?

Comment: I added an example to show using an output stream to write to the file instead of export-csv. This should not only use minimal memory, but be fairly performant as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is how I modified the script
The groups.txt file contains a list of Active directory groups for example:
group1
group2
group3
Then, the cmdlts get-QADGroupMember extracts for each group its members, the result would be something like the following
group1 | member1 | user
group1 | member2 | user
group1 | group30 | group
group2 | member1 | user 
group2 | member5 | user
group2 | member7 | user
When I tried to execute the new script, it ran for 5minutes then stopped and nothing happened, any idea?

Comment: The new script modified as you suggested {code}
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "C:\test\groups.txt"
$outstream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\test\groupMembers.csv"
while ($line = $file.ReadLine()) {
  $group=$_ 
  get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 | 
  select-object sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type
  $s = "`"{0}`",`"{1}`",`"{2}`"" -f ($sAMAccountName,$GroupName,$type)
  $outstream.WriteLine($s)
}
$file.close()
$outstream.close()
{code}

Comment: It doesn't look like you are assigning values to $sAMAccountName,$GroupName,$type anywhere in that code.

Comment: The two lines `get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 |
  select-object sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type` are supposed to have as output a list of Member|Group|Type for each group, can you tell me how to assign this values to the onew below?

Comment: You'd need something like: $groupMember = get-QADGroupMember "$_" -PageSize 500 -sizelimit 0 | select-object sAMAccountName,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}},type

Then do $groupMember.SAMAccountName etc.... As you have it written, the line with get-QADGroupMember isn't being assigning the output to any variable so you are unable to use the results of piping that function's output into select-object.

Select-Object doesn't automatically assign values to variables.